# Django migrations. Complex update

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

i have model like this:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created_at = models.DateTime()
```

Suppose, we have following categories: `[A, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, C]`. What i need, is to update records, where `category==B2`(~2.3 million records) with either category `B2`, `B3`, `B4` or `B5`.

Rule is, if, for number `n` it's first(ordered by `created_at` field) consecutive record with `category==B2` then leave category as is, if it's second consecutive record with `category==B2` -- update category to `B3`, if third, then update category to `B4`, etc. If previous record has category `B2`, but current has category `A` then reset this counter.

Comment: That seems complex enought to deserve it's own script, I don't think you should use migrations at all

Comment: @yorodm why not use migrations, what downsides?

Comment: I'm not saying "don't use migrations", I'm saying (IMHO) you should consider writing a separate script to accomplish the task given it's complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is solution i finally used:

```
category_to_pks = {}
b2_models = Model.objects.filter(category=Category.get_b2())

for number in b2_models.order_by('number').distinct('number').values_list('number', flat=True):
    number_models = b2_models.filter(number=number).order_by('created_at')
    current_year = None
    current_month = None
    category_pk = Category.CATEGORY_B2

    for model in number_models:
        if model.created_at.year == current_year and model.created_at.month == current_month:
            if category_to_pks.get(category_pk):
                category_to_pks[category_pk].append(model.id)
            else:
                category_to_pks[category_pk] = [model.id]

            if category_pk != Category.CATEGORY_B5:
                category_pk += 1

            if current_month == 12:
                current_year += 1
                current_month = 1
            else:
                current_month += 1

        else:
            category_pk = Category.CATEGORY_B3

            current_year = model.created_at.year
            current_month = model.created_at.month

            if current_month == 12:
                current_year += 1
                current_month = 1
            else:
                current_month += 1

for category_pk, model_pks in category_to_pks.items():
    Model.objects.filter(pk__in=model_pks).update(
        category=Category.objects.get(pk=category_pk)
    )
```